# Displaying image is slow in React Modal

Tags: reactjs, image, modal-dialog

I have a React modal in which I want to display images. The images are stored in my public folder, so every modal retrieves their image url like this :

```
const path = `/tooltipImages/${imageName}.webp`;
```

However, when my modal opens, images are not directly displayed and take their time. I tried adding a  component and doing this :

```
    <img
      src={`${path}?w=0.4&h=auto&fit=crop&auto=compress`}
      srcSet={`${path}?w=0.4&h=auto&fit=crop&auto=compress`}
      alt={t(`label.${name}`)}
      loading="eager"
      onLoad={() => setLoading(false)}
      decoding="sync"
    />
```

but nothing seems to improve performance. Any advice ?